# Convert number string to weekday

Tags: python, date

How do I convert `20230102` to `Monday`?

Using python, I need to accomplish this. I have a column of numbers in the format `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: Do you use Pandas?

Comment: I suggest you google "convert string to date python" for some tips.

Answer (score 2):

**P**arse with str**p**time and **f**ormat with str**f**time:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> n = 20230102
>>> datetime.strptime(str(n), "%Y%m%d").strftime("%A")
'Monday'
```

See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for documentation of the % strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `weekday()` method.

```
from datetime import date import calendar
my_date = date.today()
calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]  #Friday
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert number string into weekday using "datetime" module

```
import datetime

def get_weekday(date):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
    return date.strftime('%A')

print(get_weekday('20230102'))
```

This is how you can achieve your desired output.